# How to linq to split string (only if delimer exists) and create array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, split, c#-6.0

```
public class itemObject { public string items; }

   values - item = "name1,name2" or items = "item3"
```

Need linq to split by ',' if exists else one string array.

Comment: Where is the string to split, desired output and failed attempt?

Comment: "else one string array" containing what?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but you might want to check out the [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? E.g. had a look at `String.Split`?

Comment: that faced due to another string parsing issue, was found initially because of split delimiter. my mistake on it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesnt require linq, its the default behaviour of `String.Split`

```
var array = items.Split(',');
```

Comment: Ok. Found now, faced another issue in string so, it leads exception. was encounter because of split string initially.